# Every sequence with $\lim x_n=c$, show that $f$ is continuous at $c$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and $c \in S$, such that for every sequence ${x_n} \in S$ with $\lim x_n=c$, the sequence ${f(x_n)}$ converges. Show that $f$ is continuous at $c$.

Comment: You should specify what $S$ is.

Comment: I edited the codomain to  be  $\mathbb{R}$, please correct it if it changes your meaning.

Comment: No, the proposition clearly is meant to work with $S$ being any space in which the limit of a sequence is a meaningful concept.  (I believe any topological space would fit tat description, but since the questioner tagged this as real analysis, I suppose one could assume $S$ has a metric.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to show the converse: if $f(x)$ is not continuous, then there exists a sequence where $x_n\to c$ but $f(x_n)\not \to f(c)$.

By definition of continuity, if $f$ is not continuous, then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that, for all $\delta>0$, there exists an $x_\delta$ so $|x_\delta-c|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(c)|>\epsilon$. Now, choose $\delta=\frac1n$ to get a sequence $x_{1/n}$, and argue why this is the sequence you want.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that $S\subset\mathbf{R}$, we can work in the following way. We should know first that a function $f: S\to\mathbf{R}$ is continuous at $c\in S$ iff for all sequences $(x_n)$ in S such that $x_n\to c$, then $f(x_n)\to f(c)$. Therefore, in this case we would like to prove that for all sequences $(x_n)$ in S such that $x_n\to c$. I will only leave a few key steps to follow

- Let $(x_n)$ be some sequence in $S$ such that $x_n\to c$
- Build a sequence $y_n$ that goes $x_1, c, x_2, c, x_3, \dots$ and we can note that it converges to $c$
- By assumption then $f(y_n)$ converges

Then we can work from there to reach our conclusion.